# Multiplying using the forEach

Tags: javascript

If I create a string like

```
mutiples=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want to be able to use .forEach to multiply them all together, how do I go about that? My best guess is:

```
var total=0
multiples=[1,2,3,4,5]
multiples.forEach(function(multiply) {
   total*multiply;
});
```

or
    total*=multiply?

Comment: A friendly reminder, zero times anything still equals zero.

Comment: @Nit -- The little things in life :)

Comment: You create a "string"? You mean an array. Note that you're not using jQuery here, you're using the standard JS array `.forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, even when working on it previously I realized that duh, I couldn't use 0.

Comment: Oops. Pushed enter too soon.

Thanks for the help. In my mind I knew it was an array, just wrote this too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var total = 1;

multiples = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

multiples.forEach(function(num) {
    total *= num;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.forEach` is the wrong function here. What you need is [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var multiples = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var total = multiples.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev * curr;
});
```

Although you can, obviously, do it with a `.forEach`, this type of accumulator pattern (looping over a whole array and accumulating some value) is exactly what `.reduce` is designed for.